# Cannot find view in Laravel-Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Cannot return view from my User.php file. Why the View is not found? 
I use default User.php file where at the end I add a few lines of code in order to get the view. I get the error -View not found.

```
 <?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Request;

class User extends Authenticatable
 {
  use Notifiable;

  protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
  ];


  protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
  ];


  protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
  ];
}

if (Auth::check())
 {
return view('example-component');
 }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to return a view from here?

Comment: You might want to check out this series on getting started with Laravel, https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch.  Then, you can progress to https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step to learn about Vue.

Comment: I believe you are breaking a few concepts of MVC and Web programming in general, please refer to MVC structure and Laracasts for Laravel organization https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch

Comment: It is ok to ask, and I don't want do disencourage you, but are you sure you know what you are doing? Do you know what are models for? And also, do you know what are views and routes? Like @ethris said on his answer, seems like you should step back and learn PHP in general.

Comment: You are all right. I am new to PHP. I learned Javascript.

Comment: @matticustard I will! Thank you!

Comment: @latr.88 Thank you!

Comment: @Lucas Arbex Thanks for a help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what models are for. I think that you should step back and learn PHP in general, because that's not a valid syntax.

If you want to render a view you can use web.php to "redirect" action to Controller, and them from controller inside a function you can implement your conditional and then return an appropriate view.